# How to select between different hypothesis tests based on p-value

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have the following question. I take a sample from a population and conduct different hypothesis testing on the sample, I get the following tests.

1. Z-test (mean is less than c) ==> P-value = P1
2. Z-test (mean not equal to c) ==> P-value = P2
3. t-test (mean is higher than c) ==> P-value = P3

and the significance level is ALPHA and the sample mean is m. All the tests have the same sample size and significance level. How can I select which hypothesis testing is the best based on the p-value?

Comment: I believe you would base which test you use on the sample size rather than the p-value.

Comment: @statematics All the tests have the same sample size and the same significance level.